# rsync created a bunch of empty directories even though I specifically only transferred

Tags: mac, terminal, rsync

I used this command on my mac terminal to only to sync only java files whose size had changed on the remote host:

```
rsync -rP --size-only --include="/" --include=".java" --exclude="*" /src/dir1/ remote-host:/src/dir1/
```

However, there were several `.git/objects/??/` directories in my source folder but it had no java files in it.

for eg.

```
ls .git/objects/e3 4704650cf08c9d36c8e6699cf08b6e672e532b    # file but not java
```

On the remote host it created the exact same `.git/objects/e3` folder but completely empty. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Your command descends the entire source tree from `/src/dir1`, and during this process the corresponding directories are created on the destination. You can defer the directory creation with the `--prune-empty-dirs` (`-m`) option, which means that only necessary directories are created on the destination.

The `--size-only` removes the safety of time-based comparison checking. I would strongly recommend that unless you really have a compelling reason not to use time-based checking (e.g. your source or destination does not have a correct clock) then you should use it. Add `--times` (`-t`) to your command and remove `--size-only` for this optimisation.

I've also fixed the `include`/`exclude` options so that they copy all `*.java` files.

```
rsync -rtmP --include="***/" --include="*.java" --exclude="*" /src/dir1/ remote-host:/src/dir1/
```